# Does QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory() recognize %USERNAME%?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, environment-variables, pyqt5

I 'm trying to open a directory dialog with a default directory which is written into an .ini file.

The .ini file looks like this :

```
defaultWorkingDirectory = "%%USERPROFILE%%\Documents\CAD\Working_Directory"
```

And I wrote a function in order to open the directory dialog :

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys
from os.path import expanduser
import configparser
import itertools
import re

self.home = expanduser("~")
self.defaultPath = self.home + "\Documents\OptCAD\Working_Directory"

def openDirectoryDialog(self):
    cfg = configparser.ConfigParser()
    cfg.read_file(itertools.chain(['[global]'], open('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CAD\\config.ini')))
    print(cfg.items('global')) # It returns : [('defaultworkingdirectory', '"%USERPROFILE%\\Documents\\OptCAD\\Working_Directory"')]

    cfgList = cfg.items('global')
    wDirTuple = cfgList[(0)]
    _, workingDir = wDirTuple

    print(workingDir) # It returns : "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\OptCAD\Working_Directory"

    self.directoryName = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Working Directory", workingDir, QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly))
```

Then when I open the directory dialog the default directory is not the good directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always get the user profile path using `expanduser`, what is the need of `%USERPROFILE%`? You can store relative path in your config file in your case `Documents\OptCAD\Working_Directory` and then read it in the same way as you did in a variable say, `relativeWorkingDir`. Finally join it with the user profile like this.

```
workingDir = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), relativeWorkingDir)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works ! Also, in order to operates, I have needed to remove the double quotes of `relativeWorkingDir` thanks to `newRelativeWorkingDir = relativeWorkingDir[1:-1]`

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you're trying to do is read values from the config file of program that you don't control.

The `%USERPROFILE%` syntax is windows-specific way of referring to environment variables. It won't be automatically exapnded by either Python or Qt, so you have to do it yourself:

```
import os

userprofile = os.environ.get('USERPROFILE')
workingdir = cfg.get('global', 'defaultworkingdirectory', fallback=None)

if workingdir and userprofile:
    workingdir = workingdir.replace('%USERPROFILE%', userprofile)
else:
    workingdir = os.exanduser('~\Documents\OptCAD\Working_Directory')
```